# How to subscribe to control commands from the LGSVL simulator using only ROS2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Is it possible to get the control commands i.e steering pattern from the latest LGSVL simulator? What topic should I subscribe to, to fetch this data for training later? Previously it used to be `/simulator/control/command`. Now it has changed. I would like to strictly avoid using Autoware and Apollo and just use ROS2. Has any one done it this way?
Any pointers?

If I have to change the internal code of LGSVL, any leads on how to do that?

Also if I want throttle, braking information too, how should I go about with just ROS2?

Thanks.

**Update:**
The LGSVL team have updated their code base to reflect changes to the latest simulator. I'm currently testing it out.

**Update 2:**
After testing and doing some modification to my needs, I was able collect data. The solution is to use a sensor plugin with custom topic name and type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351280/how-to-subscribe-to-control-commands-from-the-lgsvl-simulator-using-only-ros2?/) by [dr563105](https://answers.ros.org/users/53917/dr563105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After testing and doing some modification to my needs, I was able collect data. The solution is to use a sensor plugin compatible with LGSVL using custom topic name and type.

---

Originally posted by [dr563105](https://answers.ros.org/users/53917/dr563105/) with karma: 38 on 2020-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0